# which header file path does compiler use when it compile the kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, header-files

I'm reading the source files of kernel and got some questions:

1) which header file path does the compiler use when it compile the kernel?
   In the source file tree, I found a directory named 'include'.
   However, at the '/usr/include/', I can also find some kernel header files.
   which one does the compiler use?

2) some files include the headers like this: '#include ',
   but i could not find any directory called 'asm' both under the source tree
   and '/usr/include/', however, both of them have the directory called 'asm_generic'.
   When I use the command 'make headers_install', The generated files contains the 'asm'
   Does the process of compile the kernel firstly install the headers?
   And force the compiler to process them?

p.s. I want to transform the source files of kernel into a caller-callee graph to do some research. So I need some static analysis tools. I do tried the 'call-tree' but the results are full of error, could you introduce some more powerful tools?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only ask one question at a time, otherwise you completely undermine the goal of this site to be a searchable knowledge base. You may easily edit your question to reduce it to a clean, single question, and then eventually ask others in separate threads.

Comment: The copies in the source tree are used.  The files in /usr/include are distilled down exported versions for user mode program which link against the kernel at arms length.  The asm/ directory is platform specific while the kernel sources are agnostic, so the build process gets things pointed at the particular directory appropriate to the configuration being built.  You might find the `find` and `grep -r` commands interesting in your exploration...

Comment: The Linux kernel is "self-content", it doesn't depend on any libraries. This means that all the headers files that are referenced in the kernel source, are also part of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Run `make` with the parameter `V=1` and you will see the exact lines that are passed to `gcc` and other programs. This will tell you exactly what is happening (thereby answering both your questions). However, in answer to (2), no `make` does not install any headers, it just sets the include path with the `-I` parameter to `gcc`.

Comment: Also helpful is the [kbuild docs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild), especially [makefiles.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).  Generally, there are three groups.  General Linux, *include/*, architechure, *arch/arm/include* and machine *arch/arm/mach-davinci*.  These includes are dependent on a `.config` file.  Some are an **API**.  The [sparse tool](https://sparse.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) would be a good start which checks the **API**.